# What do we call this algebraic structure?

Tags: abstract-algebra

A set $S$ together with a single binary operator $\ast : S \times S \to S$ satisfying:

- associativity
- commutativity
- $a \ast a = a, \forall a \in S$

That is all.

Does this algebraic structure have a standard name? Where does it come up?

Comment: Commutative idempotent semigroup.

Comment: Is anything of interest known about this structure in specific?

Comment: Did you try typing "commutative idempotent semigroup" into Google to see what might come up, rbrowse?

Comment: Forgot to use quotes.. semilattice is what I was looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this question:

They are called (join or meet) [semilattices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semilattice#Algebraic_definition).

It is also possible to refer to it as a commutative idempotent monoid, since that is more descriptive.

Semilattices, or lattices in general, are quite commonplace. Consult the wiki pages for a lot of examples of "how they come up."